# Meaning of "almost surely" in the following context: $\lim_{t \to \infty} X_t=a$ almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a stochastic process. What does the "almost surely" mean in the following context: $\lim_{t \to \infty} X_t=a$ almost surely?

1. Option: Let $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\geq 0$ be a sequence with $t_n \to \infty$. Then there there exist a null set $N$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{t_n}(\omega)=a$ for all $\omega \in N^c$. (But this null set depends on the concrete sequence $t_n$.)
2. Option: This nullset doesn't depends on the sequence $t_n$, i.e. there exist a null set $N$ such that for each sequence $t_n \to \infty$ there holds $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{t_n}(\omega)=a$ for all $ \omega \in N^c$.

Comment: It's the second option, there exists a null set $N$ such that $\left(X_t\left(\omega\right) \right)_{t\geq 0}$ viewed as a deterministic sequence converge to $a$, i.e. $\lim_{t \to \infty} X_t\left(\omega\right) = a$. One way of understanding that limit expression is that for every sequence $\left(t_n\right)$ such that $t_n \to \infty$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} X_{t_n}\left(\omega\right) = a$.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer!